# How to remove selected wire frames from bounding box in 3D plots?

Tags: plotting

In 3D plots one can eventually hide the whole bounding box by the use
of option `Boxed -> False`. How to remove only a selected part of the wire frame that surrounds the plot?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `FaceGrids`

```
Graphics3D[Cylinder[],
 Axes -> True, 
 FaceGrids -> {{0, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}},
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @eldo! It worked so fine.