# Remove selected axes/edges in ListDensityPlot3D

Tags: plotting

How can I remove three of the edges (of axes) displayed when using ListDensityPlot3D (see image below)? The three edges "obstruct" the view and I would like to remove them, if possible, while retaining the other edges. For example, in

```
data = Table[x y z, {z, -1, 1, 2/40.}, {y, -1, 1, 2/40.}, {x, -1, 1, 2/40.}];
ListDensityPlot3D[data]
```

[image: How to remove the edges marked with red arrows?]

So far, I see that the `Boxed->False` option allows to remove all edges, but not specific ones.

[image]

Comment: Found relevant details for `Boxed` at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80609/choosing-which-edges-of-the-box-to-show-in-3d-graphics

Answer (score 1):

```
data = Table[x y z, 
       {z, -1, 1, 1/20},
       {y, -1, 1, 1/20}, 
       {x, -1, 1, 1/20}];
ListDensityPlot3D[data, 
    Axes -> True,
    Boxed -> False,
    AxesStyle -> Thick,
    AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}}]
```

[image]

or

```
 AxesEdge -> {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}}
```

[image]