# Removing some of the box in a Plot3D

Tags: plotting

In the image below, I have indicated parts of the box feature, which I would like gone. Is it possible to remove some of the box in a Plot3D, and if so, how? My code for generating the image is shown below, and I would like to know how to change it to have the desired effect.

```
 expr = ((1 - p1) p1 (-128 ((1 - p1) p1)^(3/2) (-1 + p2)^2 p2^2 + (384 (-1 + p1)^3 p1^3)/Sqrt[1/(p2 - p2^2)] + 128 Sqrt[(1 - p1) p1] (-1 + p2)^3 p2^3 (-3 + 2 Sqrt[((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1)]) + 128 Sqrt[1/(p1 - p1^2)] (3 (-1 + p1) p1 (-1 + p2)^3 p2^3 - (-1 + p2)^4 p2^4 + (2 ((1 - p2) p2)^(7/2))/Sqrt[1/(p1 - p1^2)] + ((-1 + p2)^4 p2^4)/(((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1))^(3/2) + 3 (-1 + p1)^4 p1^4 Sqrt[((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1)] - 6 (-1 + p1)^4 p1^4 (((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1))^(3/2)) + 4 (1 - p1) p1 (-128 ((1 - p2) p2)^(5/2) - 96/(1/(p2 - p2^2))^(5/2)) + 256 (-1 + p1)^2 p1^2 (((1 - p2) p2)^(3/2) + 3/(1/(p2 - p2^2))^(3/2))))/(64 (p1 - p2)^2 ((1 - p2) p2)^(3/2) (-1 + p1 + p2)^2) // Simplify;

Plot3D[If[p1 == p2, -(-1 + p1) p1, expr], {p1, 0.5, 0.999}, {p2, 0.5, 0.999}, Exclusions -> None, PlotLegends -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {Subscript[p, 1], Subscript[p, 2]}, PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> (If[#3 < 0, Lighter[RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 0.00], White] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ViewPoint -> {1.8797, -2.3832, 1.4956}, ImageSize -> {400, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: See this 
[link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59631/how-to-remove-selected-wire-frames-from-bounding-box-in-3d-plots)

Comment: Please post `minimal working examples` with your questions. Your question is about the `Frame` / `Box` and to get an answer does not require the use of a complicated function and multiple options to the `Plot3D`

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html) coordinates and [`AxisEdge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisEdge.html), we can easily position all the necessary elements:

```
Graphics3D[
 {
  Line[
   Scaled /@ {
     {0, 0, 0},
     {0, 1, 0},
     {1, 1, 0}
     }
   ]
  },
 Axes -> True,
 AxesStyle -> Black,
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
 Boxed -> False
 ]
```

[image]

Using `AxesEdge -> …`, we force the axes to be drawn on the proper sides of the plot. The missing two lines on the bottom are drawn using `Line`, with coordinates specified using `Scaled`.

I've omitted the plot itself to make it easier to see the relevant parts. You can simply combine this with the plot using [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html):

```
Show[
  Plot3D[
    If[p1 == p2, -(-1 + p1) p1, expr], 
    {p1, 0.5, 0.999},
    {p2, 0.5, 0.999},
    Exclusions -> None,
    PlotLegends -> Automatic,
    AxesLabel -> {Style[Subscript[p, 1], Black, 18], Style[Subscript[p, 2], Black, 18], Style["expr", Black, 18]},
    PlotPoints -> 100,
    ColorFunction -> (If[#3 < 0, Lighter[RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 0.00], White] &),
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    ImageSize -> {400, Automatic},
    Axes -> True,
    AxesStyle -> Black,
    AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
    Boxed -> False
  ],
  Graphics3D[
    {
     Line[
      Scaled /@ {
        {0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0},
        {1, 1, 0}
        }
      ]
     }
   ]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on trial and error

```
Show[Plot3D[
  If[p1 == p2, -(-1 + p1) p1, expr], {p1, 0.5, 0.999}, {p2, 0.5, 
   0.999}, Exclusions -> None, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style[Subscript[p, 1], Black, 18], 
    Style[Subscript[p, 2], Black, 18], Style["expr", Black, 18]}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, 
  ColorFunction -> (If[#3 < 0, 
      Lighter[RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 0.00], 
      White] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ViewPoint -> {1.8797, -2.3832, 1.4956}, 
  ImageSize -> {400, Automatic}, Boxed -> False, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, 12]], 
 Graphics3D[{Thick, Black, 
   Line[{{0.49, 0.49, -0.13}, {0.49, 1.008, -0.13}, {1.008, 
      1.008, -0.13}}], ViewPoint -> {1.8797, -2.3832, 1.4956}}]]
```

[image]